# fullcalendar rendering: getting the current cell day integer in JS and then use it as a array key

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to render the full calendar and I want each cell to be in a different color according to an array of mine that contains a color for each day of the given month. 
I get this array in Jason.
eg "json_backgrundColor [1] ='red'"
(1 being the day date number of the month. possibale array key range 1-30/31).

here is an array in jason for e.g:

```
{"1":"green","2":"blue","3":"blue","4":"yellow","5":"yellow","6":"yellow","7":"yellow","8":"yellow","9":"blue","10":"blue","11":"yellow","12":"yellow","13":"yellow","14":"yellow","15":"yellow","16":"blue","17":"blue","18":"yellow","19":"yellow","20":"yellow","21":"yellow","22":"yellow","23":"blue","24":"green","25":"red","26":"red","27":"green","28":"green","29":"green","30":"green","31":"green"}
```

my first problem is that i cannot seem to get the number of the given cell day as  an integer (1-31) in JS.

here is the code(php while echoing Js): `

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $month = $i - 1;
    $json_array_for_fullCalendar[$i] = self::convert_events_to_json_for_full_calendar($fullCalendarMonth[$i],$_POST['display_Language']);
    echo "<div id='calendar$i'></div>
    <script>
    var json = $json_array_for_fullCalendar[$i];
            var JsMonth = $month;
            var JsYear = $year;
            var json_backgrundColor = $JsonMonthBackgroudCell[$i];
            $('#calendar$i').fullCalendar({

    var moment = $('#calendar$i').fullCalendar('getDate');
            var cellDate = moment.format('d');
            events:    json,
            fixedWeekCount: false,
            defaultDate: new Date(JsYear, JsMonth, 1),
            dayRender: function (date, cell) {
            cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor[cellDate])
            },
    });


    </script>"; }
```

This code does not even render the full calendar (and this is my seconed problem).
my seconed problem is that its hard to me to render the full calendar when im trying to get the array key in js variables.

e.g for seconed problem:
when im not using a variables and i use an integer insted :

```
 dayRender: function (date, cell) {
            cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor[1])
            },
```

and when im droping this lines from the code:

```
  var moment = $('#calendar$i').fullCalendar('getDate');
                var cellDate = moment.format('d');
```

the full calendar is rendering without any problem.

I'm a bit new with communicating PHP and JS.. I tryed to find a solution for this on my own for a long time.

any suggestion?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

take a look here
    http://jsfiddle.net/z8Jfx/7/ 
and proceed from there.

var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },

```
defaultView: 'month',

dayRender: function (date, cell) {

    var today = new Date();
    var end = new Date();
    end.setDate(today.getDate()+7);

    if (date.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
    }

    if(date > today && date <= end) {
        cell.css("background-color", "yellow");
    }

}
```

});

Comment: thanks for the answer. i tried 2 diffrent options according to your code and non of them worked (but the calendar did render): 1: " var day= date.getDate();
cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor[day])}," 2. " dayRender: function (date, cell) {
cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor[date])
    },"

Comment: HI. i still need help :( can somebody have another insight on this?